# is an apostrophe necessary for the gerund in this phrase? ('within 12 months of proceedings' commencing')

Tags: gerunds

> within 12 months of proceedings commencing.

OR

> within 12 months of proceedings' commencing.

It seems to me that commencing is a gerund (noun) which is 'owned by' the proceedings. As in, 'within 12 months of John's commencing study...'. But perhaps it could also be a gerund phrase acting as a whole noun—which is what it sounds like if you write 'within 12 months of commencing proceedings'. But I don't know how to explain it!

Answer (score 1):

Both the ACC-ing and the POSS-ing structures are often available after prepositions / ing-clause introducers; [Huang_'Distinguishing between POSS-ing and ACC-ing: evidence from 'with' / 'without')'](https://zi-huang-upf.github.io/files/Zi-Huang-ConSOLE-slides.pdf) has

> - *I will present data from the BNC which involve POSS-ing and ACC-ing as complement of "with(out)".*
>
> ...
>
> *Clay won the match*...
>
> - with + ACC-ing: *with George supporting him*.
> - without + POSS-ing: *without George’s supporting him*.
> - without + ACC-ing: *without George supporting him*.
>
> BUT
>
> - with + POSS-ing: ??*with George’s supporting him*.

Examples:

- *Are you worried about John coming?* [ACC-ing]
- *Are you worried about John's coming?* [POSS-ing]
- ... *within 12 months of the proceedings commencing*. [ACC-ing]
- ... *within 12 months of the proceedings' commencing*. [POSS-ing]

but the POSS-ing alternative often sounds more than formal, stuffy, and hence is not the usual choice in such examples, even where not actually barred (Huang's example). I can see few contexts where I would choose  ... *within 12 months of the proceedings' commencing*, and none where I'd use ... *within 12 months of proceedings' commencing*

Answer (score 0):

Prescriptivists would point out that the head noun—the “true” object of the preposition *of*—is *commencing*, as can be seen in the paraphrase “within 12 months of the proceedings’ commence**ment**.” They would therefore advise using the genitive (*proceedings **’** commencing*).

But in colloquial practice, both uses are common.